# Video is not showing me use AVPlayer only audio is working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made one sample demo 
Play video on my simulator using AVPlayer.
But my problem is video is not showing where audio of that video is working.

Code is:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)AVPlayerViewController *videoPlayer;

-(IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]];
   AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
   self.videoPlayer = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
   [self presentViewController:self.videoPlayer animated:YES completion:nil];
   self.videoPlayer.player = player;
   self.videoPlayer.showsPlaybackControls=YES;
   self.videoPlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
   [self.view addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
   [player play];

}
```

## Image

[image]

Comment: [self presentViewController:self.videoPlayer animated:YES completion:nil]; remove this line

Comment: self.videoPlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds. and apply this code for player fram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I guess that the problem is in your video file. Try to download another video [mp4 video sample](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4). Add it to your project and try.
2. You don't need this code:

   ```
   self.videoPlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;   
   [self.view addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
   ```

Comment: Yes No need those two line which you maintained.I did Experiment so I put it and forgot to remove it.

Comment: I changed my video file it is going fine.Running Perfectly